# Codeigniter current_url() skip index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using below code to get `current_url()` but find that www.xxxx.com/index.php/home/xxxx. index.php is skipped in calling `current_url()`. It store www.xxxx.com/home/xxxx.
Is it really normal behavior?
If i need to include `index.php`, how to do??

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

Open config.php and do following replaces

`$config['index_page'] = ""`

to

`$config['index_page'] = "index.php"`

Answer (score 1):

can do 2 tips

1. in **config.php**

   ```
   $config['index_page'] = "index.php"
   ```
2. In **config.php**

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'www.example.com/index.php/';
   ```